# How to replace any brackets for rounded brackets using Regular Expression?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Here is code:

```
$string="{1},[2],(3),<4>";
// Replaces closing square, curly, angle brackets with round brackets
$string = preg_replace('/\{\[\</', '(', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\}\]\>/', ')', $string);
```

It didn't replace at all in that string...  Any better coding than that?

Thanks.

Comment: comment in the code should be:  // Replaces square, curly, angle brackets with round brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{[<` never occurs in your string. Use a character class or optional grouping.

```
$string = preg_replace('/[{[<]/', '(', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[}>\]]/', ')', $string);
```

Alternative non character class approach:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?:\{|<|\[)/', '(', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/(?:\}|>|\])/', ')', $string);
```

https://3v4l.org/URvcb

Comment: `(?:\{|<|\[)` is much less efficient than a character class, `[{<[]`.

Comment: This should be executed by a single `preg_replace()` call as Wiktor has shown.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
$string="{1},[2],(3),<4>";
$what = ['~[{[<]~', '~[]}>]~'];
$with = ['(', ')'];
$string = preg_replace($what, $with, $string);
echo $string;
```

Here,

- `[{[<]` - a [***character class***](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches one of the three chars: `{`,  `[` or `<`
- `[]}>]` - matches one of the three chars: `]`,  `}` or `>` (note that `]` inside the character class does not have to be escaped when it is the first char in the class).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/utIu9).

You may use a single call to `preg_replace_callback`, too:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('~([{[<])|[]}>]~', function ($m) {
    return !empty($m[1]) ? "(" : ")";
 }, $string);
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/NXjTp).

The `([{[<])` pattern captures the opening punctuation into Group 1 (`$m[1]`) and if the group is not empty after a match is found, `(` is returned, else, `)` is replaced with.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you *need* regular expressions, avoid them. This can be done by simple string replacement, e.g.

```
<?php
$string = "{1},[2],(3),<4>";
$string = strtr($string, ['{' => '(', '}' => ')', '[' => '(', ']' => ')', '<' => '(', '>' => ')']);
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex here:

```
$string = str_replace(['{','[','<'], '(', str_replace(['}',']','>'], ')', $string));
```

Or use one call to `strtr` but the array will be longer.