# How do I convert square brackets to curly bracket in text using by regular expression?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

How do I convert square brackets to curly brackets in text using regular expression?

I'm trying to convert
`[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,3],[0,2,5,0,1],[4,2,4,4,2],[3,5,1,3,1]]`
this to
`{{0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,3},{0,2,5,0,1},{4,2,4,4,2},{3,5,1,3,1}}`

Can I do it in a simple way?
I found this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636624/how-to-replace-any-brackets-for-rounded-brackets-using-regular-expression) but it's `PHP` way.

I'm trying this on an `IDE` like `IntelliJ` or online regex tester like [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Thanks.

Comment: Why not a normal `String.replace('[', '{')` (Even using `String#replace(char, char)` i.o. `(String, String)` or that regex `replaceAll`.

Comment: I mean, not code level. This is an example format of input for array on competitive programming site. I'm using java(which uses `{}` for array initialization) I need to convert every time to paste that to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex101 you can use the [PCRE2 Replacement String Conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html) trick.

**Pattern :**

```
(\[)|(\])
```

*Basically capture the brackets in seperate capture groups.*

**Substitute :**

```
${1:+\{:$1}${2:+\}:$2}
```

Or the golfcoded version

```
${1:+\{:${2:+\}}}
```

If group 1 not empty then replace with `{`.
If group 2 not empty then replace with `}`.

Test on *regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/GoOCtQ/2)*